# working with Tj and TJ Operators by using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

If we assume a PDF document "doc.pdf" which contains "hello world" as a simple string.

let us consider this code:

```
//read the document
    DDocument doc;
    doc= PDDocument.load("doc.pdf");
//extract all the pages from the document and put them in a list
    List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages(); 
//extract the page number 0
    PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(0);
//analyse the content stream
    PDStream contents = page.getContents();
    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
//parsing the extracted contents
    parser.parse(); 
    List tokens = parser.getTokens();
    for (int o = 0; o < tokens.size(); o++)  
    {
    Object next = tokens.get(o); 
//if this content is an operator
    if (next instanceof PDFOperator)  {
    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;
/and if this operator is a Tj
    if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))
    {
//now i want to access to this string
    COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(o - 1);  
    String string = previous.getString();
//rendering mode invisible the string in the document
    tokens.set(o-1, COSInteger.get(3));
    tokens.set(o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
    tokens.add(++o, new COSString(string));
    tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
    tokens.add(++o, COSInteger.get(0));
    tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
    tokens.add(++o, new COSString(""));
    tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
    }
//update the modified stream
        PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);  
        OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
        ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
        tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
        page.setContents(updatedStream);
        }
//construct a new object that contains the string "My name is Liszt" and take (15 31) as a specific position
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, false);
        PDFont font= PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        content.setFont(font, 12);
        content.beginText();
        content.appendRawCommands("15 31 Td");
        content.appendRawCommands("(My name is Liszt)Tj\n");
        content.close();
        content.endText();
        doc.save("modified_doc.pdf");          
            }
        }
```

Now, let us consider the same document "doc.pdf", but i want to write another code in which i want to verify if the document also contains a TJ operator not only Tj.

So i tried to wrote a second code but i want a help to edit it in order to resolve all my errors and achieve the same result as the first code.

```
PDDocument doc;
doc= PDDocument.load("doc.pdf");
List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages(); 
PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(0);
PDStream contents = page.getContents();
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
parser.parse(); 
List tokens = parser.getTokens();
for (int o = 0; o < tokens.size(); o++)  
{
Object next = tokens.get(o); 
if (next instanceof PDFOperator)  {
PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;
if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))
{
COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(o - 1);  
String string = previous.getString();
tokens.set(o-1, COSInteger.get(3));
tokens.set(o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
tokens.add(++o, new COSString(string));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
tokens.add(++o, COSInteger.get(0));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
tokens.add(++o, new COSString(""));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));

}else if(op.getOperation().equals("TJ")){
COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(o - 1); 
for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++)  
{
Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
if (arrElement instanceof COSString)  
{
COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement; 
String string = cosString.getString(); 
// i get errors in the instructions below 
tokens.set(o-1, COSInteger.get(3));
tokens.set(o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
tokens.add(++o, new COSString(string));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("TJ"));
tokens.add(++o, COSInteger.get(0));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
tokens.add(++o, new COSString(""));
tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("TJ"));
}
}
}                        
}
PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);  
OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
page.setContents(updatedStream);
}

//how to write this object for both Tj and TJ ?
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, false);
    PDFont font= PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    content.setFont(font, 12);
    content.beginText();
    content.appendRawCommands("15 31 Td");
    content.appendRawCommands("(My name is Liszt)TJ\n");
    content.close();
    content.endText();
    doc.save("modified_doc.pdf");          
    }
    }
```

Best Regards,

Liszt.

Comment: please format your codes so that somebody can read and help you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues in your code.

In your top code part you have

```
content.close();
content.endText();
```

you should call `endText` before `close.`

Later on, your **TJ** specific code looks like this (after formatting):

```
else if (op.getOperation().equals("TJ"))
{
    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(o - 1); 
    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++)  
    {
        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
        if (arrElement instanceof COSString)  
        {
            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement; 
            String string = cosString.getString(); 
            // i get errors in the instructions below 
            tokens.set(o-1, COSInteger.get(3));
            tokens.set(o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++o, new COSString(string));
            tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("TJ"));
            tokens.add(++o, COSInteger.get(0));
            tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++o, new COSString(""));
            tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("TJ"));
        }
    }
}
```

In your loop over `k`

1. you overwrite the positions `o-1` and `o` of the `tokens` list. While this makes sense the first time you do that (to remove the original **TJ** operation), it does not afterwards.

   I would propose explicitly removing after reading the array argument and later-on only using `add;`
2. you add **TJ** operations with merely a `COSString` before, not a `COSArray` which **TJ** expects.

   I would propose either using **Tj** for the `COSString` arguments or instead, if it shall be **TJ**, wrapping the string into an array;
3. you ignore the numeric contents of the original `previous` array.

BTW, why don't you instead of that loop simply do

```
else if (op.getOperation().equals("TJ"))
{
    COSArray previous = (COSArray) tokens.get(o - 1);

    tokens.set(o-1, COSInteger.get(3));
    tokens.set(o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
    tokens.add(++o, previous);
    tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("TJ"));
    tokens.add(++o, COSInteger.get(0));
    tokens.add(++o, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
}
```

You you will have to tell what you try to achieve in this case.

Comment: please i wrote my comment in the second answer :)